# Upgrade to MsTest V2 no longer sees my test projects

Tags: c#, mstest

I have several unit test projects, using the old built in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework reference in my project.  recently I decided to remove that and install the MsTest V2 nuget package instead.  Everything compiles, but now none of my tests are recognized.  No other code changes were made.  I can see in my project the references:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props')" />
```

and

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

any ideas why this would happen/break?

Comment: Have you tried closing and re-opening visual studio since you changed nuget packages? I personally have run in to problems where the old DLLs where still loaded in memory in Visual Studio and it did not find the tests till you closed and reopened VS.

Comment: Yeah definitely.  I've also tried the same on another project of mine where I did the same thing.  No joy

Comment: You can try looking up [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues) under their GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you still have the old Test Adapter, you should have:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.**2.0.0**\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.2.0.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets')" />
```

You have 1.2. Make sure you added both the MSTest.TestFramework and MSTest.TestAdapter nuget packages to your test project